# Use jQuery's .on() with Modernizr.prefixed()

Tags: jquery, modernizr, prefix

I just try to understand a jQuery-Script which I must use.
Now I found the following snip:

```
$currPage.addClass( outClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
    $currPage.off( animEndEventName );
    endCurrPage = true;
    if( endNextPage ) {
        onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
    }
});
```

Explenation what I already know:
`$currPage`: This is the current page. It's a `<div class="page">`
`endCurrPage`: This is a boolean which is in standard false
`endNextPage`: Is similar to the `endCurrPage`

My question is the `.on( animEndEventName,` part. The `animEndEventName` variable looks like that:

```
var animEndEventNames = {
    'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
    'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
    'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
    'animation' : 'animationend'
},
animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];
```

This code is by Modernizr.prefixed(): http://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixed

jQuery's `.on()` wait for an event, here `animEndEventName`. So how this actually works? I don't understand exactly this part...

I hope You can help me. If you need more code, just say it. But I think this is the relevant part.

EDIT:
here is the full script on github by codrops https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions/blob/master/js/pagetransitions.js

Comment: That's a normal variable, which is assigned to a string.  What part don't you understand? Are you asking how objects work? What `Modernizr.prefixed()` returns?

Comment: This code is trying to work around the fact that `Modernizr.prefixed()` doesn't return the exact event name.

Comment: i dont understand the `.on( animEndEventName`. I mean with .on(), it just wait for an action is fired. But animEndEventName is a variable which cant be fired

Comment: `.on()` doesn't _wait_ for anything; it simply adds a handler.

Comment: .on is event handler which i beleive here is on animEndEventName do this {$currPage.off( animEndEventName ); .....}

Comment: @inputError: But i don't understand why. With on() it add this event and the next step it delete it with off. Sense?

Comment: @user2413035 it deletes what ?

Comment: @user2413035 it adds the event handler, then, after it fires, detaches it. What exactly are you having trouble with understanding?

Comment: @user2413035 `transEndEventName` contains the transition end event name, relevant to the user's browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.on()` takes a *string* with the name of an event to add a handler to.

It cannot know or care whether you pass that string from a variable or a string literal.

Comment: A handler for what? Sorry i don't know why i don't understand it, actually understand javascript / jquery, but know i don't know...

Comment: @user2413035: An event handler – a function to call whenever the event with that name is raised.

Comment: @user2413035: `animEndEventName` is a _variable_. The event name if the _value_ of the variable.